# Put UITableView and datasource/delegate in separate class doesn't work (XCode 4.2)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I tried to put the delegate and the datasource of my tableview into a separate class. My problem is that it always crashes with no error. This is why I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe someone can tell me. Maybe it is also important that I'm using ARC.

So that's my simple code:

```
//ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UITableView *myTableView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

@end
```

---

```
//ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyTableViewDatasourceDelegate.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyTableViewDatasourceDelegate *test = [[MyTableViewDatasourceDelegate alloc] init];

    self.myTableView.delegate = test;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = test;
}

@end
```

---

```
//MyTableViewDelegateDatasourceDelegate.h
@interface MyTableViewDatasourceDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

---

```
//MyTableViewDatasourceDelegate.m
@implementation MyTableViewDatasourceDelegate

-  (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 1;
} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are not referencing `test` anywhere else so it gets automatically released at the end of `viewDidLoad` method. Make sure you implement `test` as an instance variable, so at least something has reference to it.

It is not required for object to be an ivar for it to persist. Take a look at `delegate` property definition:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;
```

The `assign` is crucial here, it means that this is a weak reference and UITableView won't retain this object. Note, that if it said `(nonatomic, retain)` your code would work, but it was Apple's design decision to implement it this way to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: Cool, that worked!!! Still have to get used to that. So it means that I habe to declare something as a instance variable if I don't want to get rid of it immediately?

Comment: I've modified my answer a bit, but I'd still advise reading up on ARC, since there are probably some other ways to get this right.